# Google places API for ios, only 10 results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

When you are using google places api for ios you can only get 10 results nearby. How can you show more than 10 results and browse places per category.

Regards

Aryan

Comment: The API's nearby search functionality has a callback that provides a pagination object, allowing you to fetch "more" results. It's all in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue except I can only have 5 results.
Just to clear things up, I am using the [native Google Places SDK](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/) not the web api (which have pagination).

I'm using the [autocomplete feature](https://developers.google.com/places/ios/autocomplete) which seems to be the way to get places results. I can only get 5 results and I don't see anything related to pagination in the documentation. I have the exact same code as the doc's example. Is there a way to get more results ?

Answer (score 0):

You must to increase the parameter radius. It will return you until 20 results.

If there are more than 20 results, it will return you other parameter named "next_page_token". If you want to use it, make the same request considering this parameter.